# How to convert string into bits and then into int array - java

Tags: java, string, int, bit

How to convert string into bits(not bytes) or array of bits in Java(i will do some operations later) and how to convert into array of ints(every 32 bits turn into the int and then put it into the array? I have never done this kind of conversion in Java.

```
String->array of bits->(some operations I'll handle them)->array of ints
```

Comment: please provide more details about what on earth you're doing.

Comment: I provide as much info as neeeded. I didn't want to blur it to much.

Comment: If you get asked for more details, that's a hint that more info _is_ needed.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "array of bits" in Java.

Comment: @Wug Since no help is coming from OP, my guess is that he wants a **bit stream** that he'll transform into another bit stream.

Comment: I just want to get array of 0,1 values.

Comment: No way to do it except to get bytes and convert those -- but why do you care about what's in between?  (And @MarkoTopolnik, I've never heard of a bit stream in Java any more than I've heard of bits.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman My point exactly. OP does want it, though. Of course, there is nothing in Java stopping one from formulating a bitstream abstraction.

Comment: OP, if you want an array of 0,1 values, you could get that with a `byte[]` or even a `boolean[]`, but it would be a very misguided approach since it would have at least 87% memory waste. If, on the other hand, you implemented a bit stream that stores the bits in an `int[]` or a `long[]`, that would be a drastic improvement in terms of memory footprint.

Comment: A clarification: the bit stream would be a class that internally uses **all bits** of `int`s or `long`s for storage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(string.getBytes(charset));
  // you must specify a charset
IntBuffer ints = bytes.asIntBuffer();
int numInts = ints.remaining();
int[] result = new int[numInts];
ints.get(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it as fast as I can. Looks promising.(if it will provide bits not bytes)

Comment: Like I said in other comments, there's really no way to just get bits in Java that _doesn't_ just get bytes or ints or something bigger.  (That said, bits can be easily extracted from the bytes.)

Answer (score 2):

THIS IS THE ANSWER

```
String s = "foo";
      byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
      StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();
      for (byte b : bytes)
      {
         int val = b;
         for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
         {
            binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
         }
      //   binary.append(' ');
      }
      System.out.println("'" + s + "' to binary: " + binary);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29):

```
string.getBytes();
```

Not list, it's an array but you can use it later on, even to convert it to integers.

Comment: You can't get pure bits in Java.  You can only get them "in bulk" as bytes, ints, etc.

Comment: Seriously, can't get bits from bytes? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe you can skip the String to bits conversion and convert directly to an array of ints (if what you want is the UNICODE value of each character), using `s.toCharArray()` where `s` is a `String` variable.

Comment: No i don't want to convert it to int. I need to do some operations on bits first(add some bits).

Answer (score 0):

This will convert "abc" to byte and then the code will print "abc" in respective ASCII code (ie. 97 98 99).

```
byte a[]=new byte[160];
String s="abc";
a=s.getBytes();
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: I know that stuff. I need bits -> 10101010101 this kind ; )

Answer (score 0):

May be so (I have no compiler in my current computer and don't test if it work, but it can help you a bit):

```
String st="this is a string";
byte[] bytes=st.getBytes();
List<Integer> ints=new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.addAll(bytes);
```

If compiler fails in

```
ints.addAll(bytes);
```

you can replace it with

```
for (int i=0;i<bytes.length();i++){
   ints.add(bytes[i]);
}
```

and if you want to get exactly array:

```
ints.toArray();
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, I've missunderstood you. You want to get bits.

Answer (score 0):

Note that string is a sequence of chars, and in Java each char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive). In order to get char integer value do this:

```
    String str="test";
    String tmp="";

    int result[]=new int[str.length()/2+str.length()%2];
    int count=0;

    for(char c:str.toCharArray()) {
         tmp+=Integer.toBinaryString((int)c);
         if(tmp.length()==14) {
            result[count++]=Integer.valueOf(tmp,2);
            //System.out.println(tmp+":"+result[count-1]);
            tmp="";
         }
    }

    for(int i:result) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
```