# Hash function for a String based on scalar product with random numbers

Tags: java, hash

I'm doing a college assignment that involves creating a Distributed Hash Table with a custom hash function to distribute the keys amongst the stores (nodes).

In class we learned the formal definition for a 'good' universal family of hash functions, so that the probability of collision is 1 over the size of the table (that size being prime).

The proceeding to produce the hash is the following (m size of the table):

1. w = log2(m)
2. Divide the key in parts of w bits each
3. k = m / w
4. Interpret each part as a number in [0,2^w -1]
5. Generate a vector of length k of random numbers
6. The hash is the scalar product of the parts as a vector and the vector of random numbers mod m

This procedure is proven to have said properties.

In the assignment I have to implement it for Strings as keys. However, Strings can only be (easily) divided into chars/bytes and not bits, so I cannot use w = log2(m) but rather w' = log256(m). If needed I can post the code, but I think the idea is understandable.

Is the hash function still universal using w' or do I have to divide the String into parts of w bits?

Comment: Why can not you convert the String into bits? There are many solutions for that even in stackoverflow, like:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367611/how-to-convert-string-into-bits-and-then-into-int-array-java

Comment: I can, and I've already implemented a solution that does that. My question was rather whether it would still have the same collision probability.